# Couldn't load tightdb-jni

Tags: android, realm

I wanted to try out realm.io - unfortunately I stumbled over:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at io.realm.Realm.<init>(Realm.java:108)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at io.realm.Realm.createAndValidate(Realm.java:366)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at io.realm.Realm.create(Realm.java:355)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:314)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:193)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at realm_test.ligi.de.realmtest.MainActivity$ImportAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:33)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at realm_test.ligi.de.realmtest.MainActivity$ImportAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:29)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    ... 4 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load tightdb-jni from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/realm_test.ligi.de.realmtest-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/realm_test.ligi.de.realmtest-2]: findLibrary returned null
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at io.realm.internal.TightDB.loadLibrary(TightDB.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.<clinit>(SharedGroup.java:32)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4387):    ... 13 more
```

looking into the realm-0.73.1.jar I only see a native lib for x86 - not for arm - this would explain this. But the stuff there was not reading as this lib is only for x86 - what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you conclude this?
The realm-0.74.0.jar which is included in the distribution you can download from the realm.io website or which is downloaded via jcenter has a "lib" folder which includes binaries for armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips and x86. You can see that by renaming the jar file to .zip and view the content.